# Someone answered my question and then deleted it, but I need his/her answer

Tags: support, answers, deleted-answers

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53570670/access-data-passed-from-vertex-shader-to-fragment-shader), a while ago. Someone answered my question and actually his/her answer was helpful and I was studying it, but then she/he deleted the answer! How can I figure out who answered? How can I ask her/him to post the answer again?!

Comment: I'm not sure you can given that the answerer has not been to the site in a month. A comment on the answer suggests that it would not work so perhaps you're better off not being taken down a rabbit hole.

Comment: @RobertLongson As far as I remember, it was suggested by someone's comment that the answer won't work since it is not using the question's requested tool. But I'm not concerned with any specific tool now. Any tool that works is fine!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anyone with 10,000 reputation on the site can see deleted posts. You can try asking in an associated chat room if any such users can check who the answerer was and let you know. You can then ask the answerer to consider undeleting the answer.

Alternatively, once you're bringing it up in a chat room, you can simply ask if any of the users with 10,000 reputation can take a screenshot of the deleted answer and post it in the chat room. Then you won't need to deal with the answerer at all.

Comment: Looks like a good idea. Let me try =)

Comment: I asked a very kind 10K+ user in a chat room and now I have a screenshot of the deleted answer! Thanks =)

Comment: @user3853917 You're welcome. Glad it worked.

Comment: Now I'm wondering if deleting the post would make the answer visible. User deleted post can be undeleted, but that feels like a *really* ugly/risky way to do it